# After form submit redirect to webroot/admin in case of using prefix (admin) in cakephp 3.4

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I am getting an uncertain issues while i am submitting the form from the admin section.I am using the prefix in routes.php below are the code of routes.php for prefix

```
Router::prefix('admin', function ($routes) {
    // Because you are in the admin scope,
    // you do not need to include the /admin prefix
    // or the admin route element.
    $routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'index']);
    $routes->extensions(['json', 'xml']);
    // All routes here will be prefixed with `/admin`
    //$routes->connect('/admin', ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'index']);
    // And have the prefix => admin route element added.
    $routes->fallbacks(DashedRoute::class);
});
```

**Below the are my app controller auth code :-**

```
$this->loadComponent('Auth', [
    'loginAction' => [
        'controller' => 'Users',
        'action' => 'index',
        'plugin' => null
    ],
    //'authorize' => ['Controller'],
    'loginRedirect' => [
        'controller' => 'Users',
        'action' => 'dashboard'
    ],
    'logoutRedirect' => [
        'controller' => 'Users',
        'action' => 'index',
        ''
    ],
    'authenticate' => [
        'Form' => [
            'fields' => ['username' => 'email', 'password' => 'password']
        ]
    ],
    'authError' => 'Did you really think you are allowed to see that?',
    'storage' => 'Session'
]);
```

**Below are the main user controller functions :-**

```
public function beforeFilter(\Cake\Event\Event $event)
{
    parent::beforeFilter($event);
    $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler'); 

    $this->Auth->allow(['index','logout','register']);      
}
```

**User Controller Login function set index by default :-**

```
public function index()
{
    $this->viewBuilder()->layout('adminlogin');
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {

        $user = $this->Auth->identify();
        if ($user){
            $this->Auth->setUser($user);
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        }else{
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
    }
}
```

Finally here is the Sign Up function to registered the users when i submit the registered form it will save data successfully in database then redirect to BASEURL/webroot/admin

```
public function register()
{
    $this->viewBuilder()->layout('adminlogin');     
    $this->loadModel('Users');
    $user = $this->Users->newEntity();
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->getData());
        if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The user has been saved.'));

            return $this->redirect(['controller' => 'Users','action' => 'index']);
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
    }

    $user = $this->Users->newEntity();
    $this->set('user', $user);
}
```

**User are the  login form action :-**

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create(null, ['url' => ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'index']]); ?>
```

Comment: It's not clear from any of this what the problem is. What is it doing vs what are you expecting it to do?

Comment: Hi Greg thank you for your response. Let me try to explain what problem i am facing
(1) http://example.com            lets suppose it my domain name 
(2) http://example.com/admin I have create admin using cakephp prefix routes 
(3) Then i create the login screen in admin/user/index  
(4) So by default its login screen opening in this url http://example.com/admin you can check the routes.php code above.
(5) So problem is this when i try to submit the login form it will not submit in index function it will redirect to http://example.com/webroot/admin  thats my problem.

Comment: When you look at the HTML of the login page, what's the URL that the `<form>` element has as its target? If it includes `/webroot`, then I'd have to guess that there's a problem somewhere else with your configuration and/or directory structure.